# How to have a database that can hold millions of field of data in Django?

Tags: sql, django, database, postgresql, django-models

So I've been coding python and more specifically using Django to build web applications. I've been building an app that I would eventually like to put out onto the web and since this app has a total of six models(a number which would most likely increase in the future) and each have about 3-6 model fields, I am worried that the database would reach its limit too fast even using a database such as PostgresSql. So my question is how could I cope with such a scenario and have a database that can store millions of fields of data? I know instagram uses django and they have hundreds of millions of users, so how could I replicate that large of a database?

Comment: Millions of *fields* or millions of *rows*? Millions of rows shouldn't be an issue for PostgreSQL. BTW, Instagram [used PostgreSQL as recently as 2015](https://instagram-engineering.com/instagration-pt-2-scaling-our-infrastructure-to-multiple-data-centers-5745cbad7834), not sure about now.

Comment: its because i read somewhere that postgresSql maxes out at 1600 columns which is nothing so thats why im unsure of the scaling

Comment: That is 1600 columns in 1 table and you can have about 1.5B tables.  See [Postgres limits](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/limits.html). I don not know Django bit what I seen it seems a table maps to a model and a column to as field.

Comment: That's why I'm asking if you mean millions of columns or rows. Millions of columns is a bit odd, millions of rows is normal.

Comment: See this is my confusion. Say in django i have like 2000 registered users, wont that require 2000 columns but since its limited to 1600 you cant do that.

Comment: Wait never mind I understand now. I watched a video. Thank you guys for helping.